# How to get Position(x,y Coordinates) of an image on JPanel

Tags: java, imageicon

how to get position (x,y Coordinates)of image in JPanel

Actually I'm making pacman game. Pacman(image) moves in maze in Jpanel.I want to know the xy coordinates of pacman(image) to check the position of image.

```
public class Pacman extends JPanel{

public Image pacLeft  ;
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int xa = 0;
int ya = 0;
private Board board;

Pacman(Board board){
    this.board = board;
    pacLeft = new ImageIcon("pac.png").getImage();
}
public void move(){
    if(x + xa > 0 && x + xa < board.getWidth()-pacLeft.getWidth(board))
        x = x+xa;
    if(y + ya > 0 && y+ya < board.getHeight()-pacLeft.getHeight(board))
        y = y+ya;

}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   g.drawImage(pacLeft,x,y,this);
}


public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT){
        xa = -1; 
    }

    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        ya = -1;
    if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        ya = 1;

}
public void KeyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    xa = 0;
    ya = 0;
}


}
```

Comment: Which x and y coordinates do you need? Since you're asking I assume it's not those that you already use for drawing the image. And what are you planning to do with those coordinates?

Comment: @greybeard corrected :)

Comment: @Thomas image's(pacLeft) coordinates , which changes on pressing key

Comment: I still don't get it. Here you are already using coordinates: `g.drawImage(pacLeft,x,y,this);`, aren't those the ones you want?

Comment: I already found this . Anyway thanks !